# hyperlink is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage named RegisterApplicants and another page named ApplicantLogin consisting of a hyperlink label so that if anyone is not registered they can navigate to page RegisterApplicants. But when i click on it, its not redirecting to that page, same page is coming up again. I have used this command for hyperlink.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/RegisterApplicant.aspx">Register Now! </asp:HyperLink>
```

My RegisterApplicant page is also not visible when i m running it i dont know why?
What to do now ?

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/RegisterApplicant.aspx">Register Now!</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="addDevelopmentPlan" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page.aspx">link</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: yes i did the same piece of code still its not working

Comment: can you bind    hyperlink1.NavigateUrl="Applicant.aspx"   throw code behind

Comment: I set it from properties then i also checked in the code. but nothing happens.

Comment: your are using  Link inside updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

If using asp control is not necessary, you can try below,

```
 <a href='<%= String.Format("RegisterApplicant.aspx") %>'>Register Now</a>
```

Comment: will you please show the block of code where u putted hyperlink control?

Comment: <h4>
                            Don,t have an Account? 
                            
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/RegisterApplicant.aspx">Register Now!</asp:HyperLink>
                            
                        </h4>
                    </div>